# Converting intBitsToFloat in GLSL and floatBitsToInt back in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, webgl

I'm trying to encode an integer identifier in GLSL 3.3 shader to a Float output using `intBitsToFloat` (I'm using highp output float vector), then I use `readPixels` to get this value into `pixelData = new Float32Array(4)`. Then I decode it back to Int in JS using `floatToIntBits(pixelData[0])`, where

```
var int8    = new Int8Array(4)
var int32   = new Int32Array(int8.buffer, 0, 1)
var float32 = new Float32Array(int8.buffer, 0, 1)

var floatToIntBits = function (f) {
    float32[0] = f
    return int32[0]
}
```

And now I've got a very strange results. Namely, when I:

- encode in GLSL a value from range `[0,2^23-1]`, I get always `0` in JS
- encode in GLSL a value from range `[2^23,...[`, I get the correct value in JS
- encode in GLSL a value from range `[-2^23+1,-1]`, I get always `-2^23+1` in JS
- encode in GLSL a value from range `]..., -2^23]`, I get the correct result in JS

Does anyone have any idea why it could happen?

Comment: GLSL 3.3 doesn't exist in WebGL. WebGL2 only supports GLSL ES 3.0. In any case though, just curious if you want ints why not write out ints to an int format texture via a framebuffer and then read ints with readPixels? 
 http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/v89hgopm/

Comment: @gman Oh, I was sure WebGL2.0 bases on 3.3, my bad. Interesting, `intBitsToFloat` is available in my GLSL, but its probably not standard then and vendor specific. Regarding passing Ints directly ... I was sure it is impossible! I was referring to the Internal Format / Format / Type compability table here (and it does not list RGBA32I type): https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#TEXTURE_TYPES_FORMATS_FROM_DOM_ELEMENTS_TABLE

Is this table incomplete or am I missing some information?

Comment: That table is only for the version of `texImage2D` that takes a `TexImageSource` (an HTMLElement like an image or canvas or video). The version of `texImage2D` that just takes an array buffer supports all the formats listed in the OpenGL ES 3.0 spec a copy of which is listed [here](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-data-textures.html).  `intBitsToFloat` is part of GLSL 3.0 ES so it's fully standard. Just pointing out if you're expecting GLSL 3.3 you'll be disappointed. WebGL2 is [GLSL 3.0 ES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf)

Comment: @gman that clarifies a lot, thank you so much for you help! I was confused by the table, didn't notice is only for some particular arguments as it was just linked from these docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D

Comment: Those docs are wrong. I'll go fix them

Comment: @gman: this documentation seems then to be broken as well, it does not list possibility to readPixels using INT format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels

Comment: Those docs are for WebGL1. No one has updated them for WebGL2. Those docs are not official. The official docs are [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) and the WebGL2 spec refers to [OpenGL ES 3.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf) which lists the formats that work with readPixels in section 4.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess it's because you're using a function instead of reading the values directly out of the results of `readPixels`.  Javascript only has 1 number type which is effectively a C/C++ `double` so the moment you read any value out of a typedarray it gets converted to a `double`

Let's test without GLSL

```js
const i32 = new Int32Array([
  123,
  -123,
  20000000,
 -20000000,
]);
console.log(i32[0], i32[1], i32[2], i32[3]);
const f32 = new Float32Array(i32.buffer);

var int8    = new Int8Array(4)
var int32   = new Int32Array(int8.buffer, 0, 1)
var float32 = new Float32Array(int8.buffer, 0, 1)

var floatToIntBits = function (f) {
    float32[0] = f
    return int32[0]
}

console.log(floatToIntBits(f32[0]), floatToIntBits(i32[1]), floatToIntBits(i32[2]), floatToIntBits(i32[3]));
```

The result I get above above is

```
123 -123 20000000 -20000000
123 -1024065536 1268291200 -879192448
```

In other words, I'm guessing you're calling `gl.readPixels` something like this

```
const pixels = new Float32Array(width * height * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT);
```

Now the pixels are Float32s.

You then get one like this

```
const v = pixels[someOffset];
```

At this moment `v` has been converted to a double. It's no longer the int bits you wanted.  Instead do this

```
const pixels = new Float32Array(width * height * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT);
const intPixels = new Int32Array(pixels.buffer);
const v = intPixels[someOffset];
```

To clarify, **the moment you pull a value out of a typedarray it is converted to a double**

Let's say you did

```
console.log(floatToIntBits(pixels[0]))
```

That translated to what actually happens is

1. A float32 value is pulled out of pixels at byte offset 0 * 4
2. That value is converted to a double **DATA LOST HERE**
3. floatToIntBits is called with this double value
4. floatToIntBits converts `f`, the already bad data double into a float32 as it puts it into the `float32` array
5. floatToIntBits gets an int out of int32
6. that int is cast to a double
7. that double is returned
8. that double is passed to `console.log`

Compare to

```
console.log(intPixels[0]);
```

That translated to what actually happens is

1. an int32 value is pulled out of intPixels at byte offset 0 * 4
2. That value is converted to a double
3. That double is passed to `console.log`

A double can hold a 53 bit integer without loss of precision so converting an int32 to a double loses no data. Where as then you pulled the value out as a float it was also converted to a double but converting a float to a double doesn't keep the bits the same so when you try to read out the bits as an int they're no longer the bits you expect.

That said, if you just want ints you can create an int texture, attach it to a framebuffer, render integers into it, and read them out as integers.

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
const tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA32I, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA_INTEGER, gl.INT, null);
log('errors:', gl.getError() !== gl.NONE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
log('errors:', gl.getError() !== gl.NONE);
const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
log('errors:', gl.getError() !== gl.NONE);
// just for sanity check: spec says this should work
const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
log('fb good:', status === gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);

gl.clearBufferiv(gl.COLOR, 0, [-456, -123, 789, 112233]);

const pixel = new Int32Array(4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA_INTEGER, gl.INT, pixel);
log('pixel:', pixel);

log('errors:', gl.getError() !== gl.NONE);


function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: That's a good guess, but I was very careful not to make this implicit conversion. I was using it exactly as I stated in the question, which is `floatToIntBits(pixelData[0])` without any additional variable. I was also testing it without GLSL and it works well. The interesting thing is that when I'm sending values smaller than `2^23` from GLSL I just get buffers filled with 0 in JS (inspecting the buffers behind the typed arrays). Of course my problem is solved with the Int type from your comments above, still I'm wondering what is happening here. I'll try to investigate it further! Thank you

Comment: You don't need an explicit variable. The fact that you pulled out out of the buffer and passed it to a function means it was already converted to a double the moment you pulled it out of the buffer to pass to the function. Don't pull it out of the buffer as a float, pull it out of the buffer as an int

Comment: Got it! Ahh, it's so simple and so obvious after all. Thank you @gman!