# Bit accurate float rendering

Tags: webgl2

How can I reliably render bit accurate outputs to a floating-point texture?

I am trying to encode `uint` values with the `intBitsToFloat` function within a shader and write the result to an `RGBA32F` texture. This is meant as a workaround for the inability to alpha blend integer textures, and I, later on, want to decode the float values back to their initial `uint` value.

This is the shade code used

```
output_id.r = intBitsToFloat(input_symbol_id);
output_id.g = intBitsToFloat(input_instance_id);
output_id.b = 0.0
output_id.a = alpha > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
```

where `input_symbol_id` and `input_instance_id` are the `int` values I want to encode.

This doesn't seem to work, though. The output for very small values (e.g., `intBitsToFloat(1)`) always gets truncated to `0.0` when later reading from the output texture via `readPixels`. Larger values (e.g., `1.0`) seem to get passed through just fine.

This is using weblg 2.0.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977514/converting-intbitstofloat-in-glsl-and-floatbitstoint-back-in-javascript), which describes a similar problem. I am however, already employing the fix described there, and I still only get zero values back.

Comment: Your other question had the correct answer. You have something else wrong. Blending is not the solution

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What do you mean by "Blending is not the solution"?